# JavaScript UDF fails in Airflow but works in Snowflake

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below function which works when I run in snowflake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dfp.extract_vcode(NAME VARCHAR)
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE javascript
    STRICT
    AS '
    const regex = /[[]v=([0-9]+)/ig;
    let s = NAME.match(regex);
    if (s != null) {
        return s[0].split('=')[1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    ';
```

but when I test in Airflow:

common.snowflake.exceptions.SQLCompilationSnowflakeException:

> 001003 (42000): 019eb4f7-0603-05d7-0000-01b529072596: SQL compilation
> error: parse error line 6 at position 35 near ''. syntax error
> line 6 at position 4 unexpected 'const'.
>
> Error occured while processing
> query(019eb4f7-0603-05d7-0000-01b529072596):
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dfp.extract_vcode(NAME VARCHAR) RETURNS
> string LANGUAGE javascript STRICT AS ' const regex = /[[]v=([0-9]+)/ig

----- I have another UDF that works fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dfp.parse_metadata(DATA varchar)
    RETURNS OBJECT
    LANGUAGE javascript
    STRICT
    AS '
    if (!DATA) {
        return {}
    }

    let dict = {}
    const parts = DATA.split("|")

    parts.forEach((p) => {
        const split = p.split("=")
        dict[split[0]] = split[1]
    })

    return dict
    ';
```

Comment: Please add your Airflow code.

Comment: @Elad I added what I have in the my .sql code above, that is what is giving me the error

Comment: If this SQL runs as is on Snowflake then the issue is either with Airflow code or with the snowflake python sdk. To know we need to see your code. Since this is a syntax error most likely your query isn't running on Snowflake either. Did you check this?

Comment: Yes it working in Snowflake, I tested it. The error is saying it's with 'const' but when I changed it to var and added an 'if' statement it gives the same error

Comment: @Elad also I've added another UDF we're using that works fine in Airflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Snowflake will try to split SQL passed to it into multiple statements separated by ';' and the parser that is used there does not understand the javascript syntax.

The solution is to wrap your sql query with []. If you pass single-element array to the Snowflake Operator, it will assume each element of the array is a single statement and it will not even try to split it.

Comment: thanks for responding. You mention to wrap my query with [], this part of my query is using the UDF.:
select
        COALESCE(
        DFP.extract_vcode(NAME),
        DFP.extract_vcode(NAME_5),
        DFP.extract_vcode(NAME_4),
        ) as display_vertical_code
    FROM dfp.ads au
),
Do I have to to wrap this entire part in [ ] ??

Comment: Oh I see, what you mean, I had to read it more carefully. I removed the   ; after each line and that worked as well. thanks

Comment: Cool! What I meant is to wrap the whole sql in operator call. Where you had `sql= "CREATE"` .... it should be `sql = [ "CREATE..." ]`